# Haskell Get position from first digit in string

Tags: string, haskell, char, position, int

What I got is

```
digitIndex :: String -> Int
digitIndex [] = 1
digitIndex (x:xs) =
    if
        isDigit x == True
    then
        -- Count list
    else
        -- Create list with x(x is not a digit)
```

What my idea is is to make a list with all the x that he is passing so when he passes a digit he only needs to count the list and that will be the position of the digit(when you count a +1).

Only thing is I don't know how to get the job more done. Can you guys help me out with tips?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. If it is necessary to remove them, flag for moderator attention and ask for removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the normal recursion:

```
digitIndex :: String -> Int
digitIndex [] = 0
digitIndex (x:xs) = if isDigit x
                    then 1
                    else 1 + digitIndex xs
```

If the first character itself is a digit, then the function returns `1` else it just adds `1` and passes the remaining string (`xs`) to the function and the recursion goes on.

Also note that the above function doesn't work properly when the `String` doesn't have a number at all.

And also checking `isDigit == True` isn't necessary.

Comment: That wont make the good output because if I fill in: digitIndex "hel3lo" it will output 1 and not the 4 (the 3 is in the 4th place of the string)

Comment: @user3434886 I understood your question wrongly, have updated the solution.

Comment: Maybe I needed to be more clear in my explanation but you solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `findIndex`:

```
import Data.List

digitIndex :: String -> Int
digitIndex = maybe 0 id . findIndex isDigit
```